# Running MVN INSTALL with OPENCMIS

Tags: java, maven, opencmis, openkm

I´m trying to set up the OpenCMIS InMemory Repository following the instructions from Apache but I keep getting the following error when running the Maven command `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/openkm/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-client/chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings/src/main/java/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/bindings/impl/ClientVersion.java:[29,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getDefinedPackage(String)
[ERROR] location: class ClassLoader
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings
```

Comment: En inglés por favor.

Comment: I´m trying to set up the OpenCMIS InMemory Repository following the instructions from Apache but I keep getting the following error when running the maven command mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Comment: You can edit your question via the _Edit_ link under the tags.

Comment: Please add a link to the instructions you mention. Are you sure that you declared all necessary `<dependency>`s in your POM?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've been just following the instructions from the file, wich can be found here http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html in "Documentation"

Comment: Which file do you mean? I neither see any code samples nor a link to any on the page [Apache Chemistry CMIS Code Samples](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/#apache-chemistry-cmis-code-samples). There's just a dependency declaration for different build tools and OSs.

Comment: Ít's right bellow that link, here https://github.com/cmisdocs/ServerDevelopmentGuideV2/blob/master/docs/OpenCMIS%20Server%20Development%20Guide%20-%202nd%20Edition.pdf?raw=true

Comment: Are you sure that you want to build this yourself, rather than just using the libraries in your own project?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I don't have the time to go through a 66-pages PDF. What I can tell you is that the PDF's last technical update is from 2014 and that [the POM of the sample project](https://github.com/cmisdocs/ServerDevelopmentGuideV2/blob/master/pom.xml) contains `<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin<version>3.0...<target>1.7...<source>1.7`. That's utterly outdated and is surely not going to work with more recent JDKs.

Comment: It's ok, thak you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The [*OpenCMIS Server Development Guide (2nd Edition)* PDF](https://github.com/cmisdocs/ServerDevelopmentGuideV2/blob/master/docs/OpenCMIS%20Server%20Development%20Guide%20-%202nd%20Edition.pdf?raw=true)'s last technical update is from 2014 and the [POM of the sample project](https://github.com/cmisdocs/ServerDevelopmentGuideV2/blob/master/pom.xml) contains:

```xml
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <source>1.7</source>
```

That's utterly outdated and is surely not going to work with more recent JDKs.